# Angular4 Routing Method

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have the following routing in an angular project:

```
const sampleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':fruit/show',
  },
  {
    path: ':fruit/edit'
  },
  {
    path: ':fruit/update'
  }
];
```

and I want to change it into a format like this:

```
const sampleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':fruit/',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'show'
      },
      {
        path: 'edit'
      },
      {
        path: 'update'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

However, Angular cannot catch the above routing. Does anyone know how to configure like this? Appreciate for any help.

Comment: There is no such thing as "angularjs4".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your information,
the correct routing should be like this:

```
const sampleRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':fruit',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'show'
      },
      {
        path: 'edit'
      },
      {
        path: 'update'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Remove the `/` after `:fruit` will get the correct routing.